# Facebook C# SDK Post Image Or Link To Fan Page

Tags: c#, facebook

how i post Image on my fan Page , it's show as My User Post in Page not Page it self Post It

```
result = app.Post("/[ID]/feed", new Dictionary { { "link", "http://www.page.com" } });
```

[image]

i make an image to descripe a problem here : [Problem Image](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=447725135266087&set=a.447584021946865.95623.446726068699327&type=1&theater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I need to get my access token from [get your access token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/)
2. as read [API document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/):

   go to the https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[your access taken from 1.]
    it will get your all permission access taken, search for your Page
    use this access taken and it will work Fine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post as a page you must acquire a page accesstoken,

manage_pages is the permission you need to get the page access_token, and then request  /USER_ID/accounts

If you want and access_token that don't expires, you need to use a new endpoint, documented here. Scenario 4 and 5

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

If you want anything done through the API appear as been done “by” your page, you have to get a *page* access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/